# Can SmartMeter run a scenario written in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, smartmeter

I've a simple scenario written in JMeter. Now I want to use SmartMeter instead of JMeter, but I don't know if I have to create a new scenario/test or if can reuse the old one?

I speak about http://www.smartmeter.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an environment of SmartMeter Editor we can run the Test 1:1, then it is virtually identical run as in JMeter 2.12 and it does not use distributed mode. But we can watch the test in the Runner tab and after the test to generate the report (if the listener "[et@sm - Controller Summary Report](http://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-scenario-steps)" is included the test).

For a distributed mode we recommend using SmartMeter Thread Group "[et@sm - Distributed Lazy Stepping Thread Group](http://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-thread--users----threads-groups)", which creates users at the moment of their involvement in a testing process and they are also automatically distributed to generator servers with exact deviation between them and keeping the number of VU from the settings.

You also need to add a component of listener "et@sm - Controller Summary Report" to store the results and display informations in SmartMeter runner.

Further adjustments are voluntary, but I can only recommend them:
To use assert "et@sm - Better Response Assertion" which works much more efficiently and faster ; To retrieve values ​​from the response exploit "et@sm - Boundary Points Extractor" etc.